# Fancybox display issues on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, fancybox

I'm using the Fancybox on [this](http://www.unctv.org/tWxkBbq_10M6wKRRL/t/home19_j.htm) page.

I've set it to show the videos in the top carousel in a Fancybox only
if the browser is Safari/iPad. If you click one of the videos in the
top content carousel, you'll see some extra lines outside of the
Fancybox. Plus, you'll see that the title item (set to titlePosition:
"outside") has some funky corners -- they're off by a pixel or two.

On the iPad, if you tap the "Click to See a Gallery of Popular Thank
You Gifts!" toward the middle, bottom of the page, you'll see some
extra lines outside of the Fancybox when it pops up.

This all works fine on Windows Safari 5. Any solutions?